# Facing issues with CacheControl inside REST Webservices

Tags: rest

I am using this part of code inside my webservice (Jersey REST Webservice calls) to speed up the application by providing cache

```
         CacheControl cc = new CacheControl();
         cc.setMaxAge(300000);
         cc.setPrivate(true);
         httpresponse.addHeader("Cache-Control", cc.toString());
```

But i see that after sometime , the respinse being returned is empty ??

(database chnages are  happening)

Could you please let me know what could be the reason for this ??

Comment: tty to use solution from http://alex.nederlof.com/blog/2013/07/28/caching-using-annotations-with-jersey/